# Getting the filter query right while displaying db data in wordpress pages

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Am trying to display some filtered data from a custom database of wordpress. but it shows me wrong filtered data.

I tried Select option and LIKE option for filtered data but id didnt work.

```
global $wpdb;

// QUERY HERE TO COUNT TOTAL RECORDS FOR PAGINATION 
$total = $wpdb->get_var
    ("SELECT      *
    FROM        wpfs_teachpress_pub
    WHERE       wp.fs_teachpress_pub.author LIKE '$halgeri%'");
$post_per_page = 10;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $post_per_page ) - $post_per_page;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpfs_teachpress_pub ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $post_per_page OFFSET $offset");
$mydate = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT date FROM wpfs_teachpress_pub" );
foreach ( $result as $print )   { ?>

      <tr class="tp_publication">

              <td class="tp_pub_info"> <p class="tp_pub_author"> <?php echo $print->author; ?><br/>
              <span class="tp_pub_title"> <?php echo $print->title; ?></span><br/><?php echo $print->journal; ?> <span class="dd">Year Published: <?php echo date("Y", strtotime($print->date)); ?></span> </p>

      </tr>

        <?php }

  ?>
```

Currently it doesn't filter data that includes "Halgeri" as its author from author column.

Note: My author column structure "Halgeri; some autherx; some authory"
so one publication may contain diffrent authors but want to show "Halgeri's" all publications.

Comment: Did you mean for $halgeri to be a variable?

Comment: No it's just data from author column, this column does have many authors and i want to filter our only "Halgeri" author's data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. - But I can't help feeling that you meant to say `SELECT * FROM wpfs_teachpress_pub WHERE wp.fs_teachpress_pub.author LIKE '%halgeri%'`

Answer (score 0):

You have not applied filter query in $result. Please check it.$total and $result both have a different query. $total's query seems to be perfect.